# Removing top bar and colours in blocks

Tags: beamer

I want to remove the top horizontal dark blue bar only in the first slide, and also use that dark blue color with white letters in the block of the same first slide. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]

  \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3.1ex,dp=2ex]{section in head/foot}%
     \hspace*{10.5pt}\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{noheadline}{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    {%
    \leavevmode%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3.1ex,dp=2ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{10.5pt}\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
    }
    \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{noheadline}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\centering \textbf{My slides}
\end{minipage}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{noheadline}

\section{My slides}

\begin{frame}

My first slide

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- in your `noheadline` environment you explicitly replace the normal headline by a dark blue bar. If you don't want this bar, don't make this replacement.
- to change the colour of the block, you can use `\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=section in head/foot.bg,fg=white}`

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]

  \usetheme{JuanLesPins}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3.1ex,dp=2ex]{section in head/foot}%
     \hspace*{10.5pt}\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{noheadline}{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip\headheight}
}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{noheadline}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=section in head/foot.bg,fg=white}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\centering \textbf{My slides}
\end{minipage}
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{noheadline}

\section{My slides}

\begin{frame}

My first slide

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]